# how to place images in the same line inside a flexbox

Tags: html, css

so for responsiveness, I have created a flexbox and placed some images inside but for some reason, I am not able to place all the images in the same line. written below is my CSS code. the container-project is the class for the div in which I am placing all the images and the project-img class is the class for every image placed inside the div.

```
    .container-projects{
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .project-img{
      width: 25%;
      height: auto;
      border-radius: 30px;
      padding: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: add ```html``` code for better problem solving.

Comment: remove `flex-wrap: wrap` and the images will stay in the same line

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues.

One is that you've set `flex-wrap` to `wrap` which means that flex items will wrap onto multiple lines, from top to bottom. Try setting it to `nowrap` instead.

The second depends on how many images you're trying to put in the line. If it's 4 then you're fine, otherwise you want to change the `width: 25%;` to a different value as at the moment it will be dividing the width of the containing area in to 4. You might want to look into the `flex-basis` property instead. It defines the default size of an element before the remaining space is distributed.

Answer (score -1):

Add `align-items: center;`

```
   .container-projects{
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
    }
```